# Equal tangent segments

Tags: geometry, circles

$AM$ and $BN$ are tangent segments to circle $k(O; R)$ at points $M$ and $N$ $(OA>R, OB>R)$. Show that line $MN$ bisects segment $AB$ if $AM=BN$.

[image]

When I initially drew a figure, I discovered that the description is incomplete; angles $OMA$ and $ONB$ have to be rotated in the same direction in order for the claim to work.

The fact that $AM = BN$ has one immediate consequence: the triangles $OMA$ and $ONB$ are congruent.

Please give me any ideas you have for what to do next, that might lead toward the desired proof.

Comment: Hint: Draw perp from $O$ to $AB$. Say it meets $AB$ at $C$. Show points $N, C$ and $M$ are collinear. For that, show $\angle BCN = \angle ACM$.

Comment: Any hints for showing $\angle BCN=\angle ACM$? How does it prove N, C and M are collinear? And what if they are? Sorry for the questions. Thank you!

Comment: If $MCN$ is a line and it intersects $AB$ then $\angle BCN = \angle ACM$, right? Please make an attempt by some angle chasing. It is not that difficult to show they are equal. If you still get stuck, post your progress.

Comment: @MathLover, well it is difficult for me. I tried to show that BCN and MCA are similar, but it seems like they are not. There isn't any other triangle with angle BCN!

Comment: $\angle BCO = \angle BNO = 90^0$, what does that tell about quadrilateral $BNCO$? Then do you see why $\angle BCN = \angle BON$? Similarly show $\angle ACM = \angle AOM$.

Comment: Why is $\measuredangle BCO=90^\circ$?? Isn't $\measuredangle BNO=90^\circ$

Comment: @MathLover, it isn't clear for me why $\measuredangle BCO=\measuredangle BNO=90^\circ$

Comment: I have an extended discussion warning so I will stop here. Did you read my hint to start with? Why is $\angle BCO$ not $90^0$ when it is foot of the perpendicular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop a perpendicular from $O$ to $AB$. Call its foot $P$. The quadrilaterals $OPNB$ and $OPAM$ are cyclic, since $<BNO=<BPO=90$ and $<OPA=<OMA=90$. Therefore, $<BPN=<BON$ and $APM=AOM$. But $<BON=<AOM$ since $OAM$ and $ONB$ are congruent. Therefore $<BPN=<APM$ thus showing that $N$, $P$ and $M$ are collinear. Therefore $P=C$. The line $OC$, being the perpendicular bisector in the isosceles triangle $AOB$, is also the median.

Answer (score 1):

Let the blue circle that passes through B, O, N cut MN at P.

[image]

Extend BP to cut MA at some point A’ (other than A).

Now, POMA’ is cyclic.

Then, $\angle MOA’ = \angle MPA’ = \angle BPN = \angle BON = \angle MOA$

This mean A’ is in fact A.

Therefore, P is the midpoint of the base AB of the isosceles triangle OAB.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Particular case, where OA is parallel with BN:

In this case right angle triangle OAM and OBN are equal, so triangle OAB is isosceles and OC is it's altitude.Now we prove that extension of NDM passes C.We connect N to C it's extension touches the circle at a point like M' and intersects AO at D.

Triangles ADC and BNC are equal due to ASA, because:

$\angle BCN =\angle DCA$

$ CBN=CAD$

$BC=CA$

Therefore $DA=BN$

But: $BN=AM$, this means  M' must be coincident on M.

Accurate drawing shows the definition is not true if OA is not parallel with BN.